# How do you read a variable from another variable

Tags: variables, lua

```
Horse_Apple = "Happy Horse"

local var = Animal() .. "_" .. Food()

print(var)
```

I hope someone here understands the problem i'm trying to solve here. Animal() returns "Horse" and Food() returns "Apple".

What i'm attempting to do is read the variable 'var' and read its value 'Horse_Apple' as a variable which should return "Happy Horse". As much as im trying to find the solution to this im failing big time, Thank you.

Comment: You might find some answers here http://howto.oz-apps.com/2011/09/creating-dynamic-variables.html / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061755/how-do-i-make-a-dynamic-variable-name-in-lua

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access a global variable by a dynamic name using `_G`, i.e.:

```
print(_G[var])
```

Normally this isn't considered good design: It's better to make `Horse_Apple` a key in some table and access that table instead, like this:

```
values = { Horse_Apple="Happy Horse" }
local var = Animal() .. "_" .. Food()
print values[var]
```

Comment: Note that the part that isn't considered good design is the part where you're using a global variable, not the part where you use `_G` to access the global table.

Comment: Thank you! Saved me one headache :)