# Setting a variable in a for loop (with temporary variable) Lua

Tags: for-loop, lua, love2d

I have a for loop in lua, and I'm trying to set variables inside that for loop using the iterator variable. I need it to set these variables:

```
damage1
damage2
damage3
damage4
damage5
damage6
damage7
damage8
damage9
damage10
damage11
```

Of course I'm not going to assign them all, as that would be breaking the rules of D.R.Y. (Don't Repeat Yourself). This is what I figured would work:

```
for i = 0, 11 do
    damage..i = love.graphics.newImage('/sprites/damage/damage'..i..'.png')
end
```

Don't mind the `love.graphics.newImage()`, that's just a function in the framework I'm using. Anyways, can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a dynamic variable name in Lua?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061755/how-do-i-make-a-dynamic-variable-name-in-lua)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set global variables, set `_G["damage"..i]`.

If you want to set local variables, you're out of luck.

Consider setting `damage[i]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I will be able to access this variable as if it was a normal variable, yes?

Answer (score 2):

If your variables are `local` variables, its impossible to do what you want since Lua erases the names during compilation. If your variables are properties of a table (like global variables are) then you can use the fact that table access is syntax sugar for accessing a string property in a table:

```
--using a global variable
damage1 = 17

--is syntax sugar for acessing the global table
_G.damage1 = 17

--and this is syntax sugar for acessing the "variable1" string property
--of the global table
_G["damage1"] = 17

--and you can build this string dynamically if you want:
_G["damage"..1] = 17
```

However, as lhf said, it would probably be much more simpler if you stored the variables in an array instead of as separate variables:

```
damages = {10, 20, 30, 40}

for i=1,4 do
    damages[i] = damages[i] + 1
end
```

Comment: I made a local table, instead of making a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be the best thing to do?

```
damages = {}

for i = 0,11 do
    table.insert(damages, love.graphics.newImage("/sprites/damage/damage"..i..".png"));
end
```

And then call by damages[0], damages[1]. etc.