# How to change names of an object in a for statement in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to create multiple objects that are the same, but want to change the names. I don't really want to use arrays. Is this possible?

```
for i=0, 3 do
  button = display.newRect(100,100,100,100)
end
```

I want the for statement to create 7 buttons with Names like this:

```
   button1 = display.newRect(100,100,100,100)
   button2 = display.newRect(100,100,100,100) 
   button3 = display.newRect(100,100,100,100)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a dynamic variable name in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061755/how-do-i-make-a-dynamic-variable-name-in-lua)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use dynamic variable names. You can however use a table indexed by a string:

```
buttons = {}
for i=0,3 do
    buttons['button' .. i] = display.newRect(100,100,100,100)
end
```

Then you can access the buttons like this: `buttons['button1']`.