# What is the name of a variable when you make it from an array (table)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
local text = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"}

for k = 0,  (#table - 1) , 1 do
local options =
    {
        text = table[k+1][1],
        x = halfW,
        y = (150*k + 150) - 175,
        font = native.systemFont,
        fontSize = 40,
        id = k

    }

text[k+1] = display.newText( options )

end
```

I have defined HalfW and table further up. What are the text objects names once the for loop has been completed? The main goal is to have 5 (#table) text objects each with a different name (Text1, Text2, etc.) that I can edit outside of the for loop also no global.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you wanting to put the `options` table inside another table that is not local to that loop?

Answer (score 1):

`table` is Lua's library for table manipulation. Assigning other values to it is not a good idea.

```
local text = {"One", "Two"}
```

is equivalent to

```
local text = {}
text[1] = "One"
text[2] = "Two"
```

In the for loop you're assigning new values from key `1` to `#table`.

So your first text object can be accessed as `text[1]`, the second as `text[2]` and so on.

Comment: I have iterated to two more approaches, but neither work. `code` local Text1
local text = {}



for k = 0,  (#table - 1) , 1 do
local options =
    {
        text = table[k+1][1],
        x = halfW,
        y = (150*k + 150) - 175,
        font = native.systemFont,
        fontSize = 40,
        id = k

    }


text[k] = display.newText( options )
text1.text = "hi"

Comment: @CheChe please refer to the Lua reference manual and find out how to access table elements. you're assigning values to numeric table keys. text1 is a nil value so you cannot index it. if you want to access the first entry in your table text use text[1] not text1...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061755/how-do-i-make-a-dynamic-variable-name-in-lua I found that this worked for my use case. Thanks for the help

Comment: @CheChe maybe next time describe what you want to achieve, not what doesn't work. I was under the impression that you failed accessing the value, not that you wanted to give it a custom name.